# How can I filter my required file in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How can I filter my required file in WebStorm?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

I have the `physical_server_list_by_model.vue` file in my project:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

but I can not find it by search the left directories.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Use `Navigate | File....` for such stuff (or `Search Everywhere`). Speed Search in Project View panel searches among **expanded nodes only** -- it will not find text in collapsed nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find file of your project by:

```
Navigate -> File
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>